# Algorithm of calculate modulo after power

Tags: c++, algorithm

Below a piece of code to calculate the value of a^b%c,

```
int powermod(int a,int b,int c)
{
    int ans = 1;
    while(b)
    {
        if(b&1)
            ans=(ans*a)%c;

        a=(a*a)%c;
        b=b>>1;
    }
    return ans;
}
```

I tried to understand the algorithm behind the code but couldn't make it.
Can someone help to explain this to me? How this works and does the algorithm behind it have a name?

Comment: take some values of a and b and try solving on paper.

Comment: Indentation corrected, thanks @JoachimPileborg

Comment: I believe that this algorithm is wrong as posted. The body of the `if` should be `ans = (ans*a)%c`, not `ans *= ...`. As it stands, it produces the wrong answer and can produce an answer greater than `c-1`.

Comment: Perhaps the algorithm is easier to understand when you look at the "pure" power function without the modulo operations.

Comment: really?  if true then it could be the reason. but actually I remember running this code gives the correct answer...

Comment: This is called Modular Exponentiation, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It use the binary thinking.

a<sup>b</sup> = a<sup>b1</sup> a<sup>b2</sup> *...* a<sup>bn</sup> when b1+...+bn=b

write b in binary, you will get a<sup>b0</sup> a<sup>2*b1</sup> a<sup>4*b2</sup> *...* a<sup>2<sup>n</sup>bn</sup> ,bi means the ith bit in binary b. It can only be 0 or 1.

Now we find out that we don't need to calculate a<sup>2<sup>n</sup></sup> every time, as we can get it from a<sup>2<sup>n-1</sup></sup>

Because of (a*b)%c=(a%c)*(b%c)%c, this algorithm do the mod operation when multiply.

Answer (score 2):

It's easier to see what's going on without the "modulo c" part:

```
int power(int a,int b)
{
    int ans = 1;
    while(b)
    {
        if(b&1)
            ans *= a;
        a=a*a;
        b=b>>1;
    }
    return ans;
}
```

This is a standard algorithm to compute a<sup>b</sup> by considering `b` one bit at a time, starting with the least significant bit. For each bit of `b`, if it is `1`, multiply the answer by the current value of `a`. Then, to move to the next bit, square `a` and shift `b` to the right by 1 bit. The theory of this algorithm is that x<sup>2<sup>m</sup> + 2<sup>n</sup></sup> = x<sup>2<sup>m</sup></sup>x<sup>2<sup>n</sup></sup>.

This type of algorithm is known as ["exponentiation by squaring"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring), "square-and-multiply" or "binary exponentiation".

The posted algorithm (after correction as noted in the comments) does the same thing modulo `c`, using the fact that `(x*y)%z == ((x%z) * (y%z)) % z` (that is, the modulo operation can be applied either before or multiplication). It uses this to keep `a` less than `c` despite repeated squaring.